# CSS. Content of a div is outside the div

Tags: html, css, overflow

For some reason the content inside my divs are outside them. I have tried `overflow:hidden` and `overflow:auto` in the container, such a `height:auto`, but nothing seems to work.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jn4144b9/1/)

### html

```
<div id="portalPage">
    <div class="containerOfSites">
        <div class="portalItem col-md-4">
            <h1>AUTOMOTIVE</h1>
            <p>web sites for the<span> automotive</span> market</p>
            <a href=""><span class="viewMorePs">GO</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="portalItem col-md-4">
            <h1>DESIGN</h1>
            <p>web sites for the small & large business for<span> all s ectors</span></p>
            <a href=""><span class="viewMorePs">GO</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="portalItem col-md-4">
            <h1>BRANDING</h1>
            <p><span>branding</span> and design</p>
            <a href=""><span class="viewMorePs">GO</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### css

```
#portalPage{
    background:url('http://i59.tinypic.com/2m780o6.jpg');
    text-align:center;
    padding:30px 50px;
}
.containerOfSites{
    display:inline;
    overflow:auto;
    height:auto;
}
.portalItem{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.portalItem span.viewMorePs{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.portalItem h1{
    color:#B5D803;
    font-weight:900;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
     font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
span.viewMorePs {
    background-color: #B5D803 !important;
    border: 2px solid #FFF !important;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size:12px;
    padding: 5px 14px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #383838;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

Does anyone has an idea about what can I do to fix it?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The reason your button is not "pushing down" your field is because it is inline element and limited by it's height to the line height. margin-bottom for inline (span) element should not have any effect by specification unless it is set to block.

```
span.viewMorePs {
    display:block;
}
```

So the solution is to set span or a to block http://jsfiddle.net/jn4144b9/15/ you'll have to deal with width but it is another question.

Comment: I agree with this answer. A `span` is not set with `display:block` by default. A `span` element is an `inline` element which is why some of the other CSS you are using is not applying to it. Set it to `display: block` so that you can then treat it as a `div`

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use overflow:hidden (worse look), you can add to your a node these attributes:

```
.portalItem a.go{
    margin:15px;
    display:block;
}
```

and, of course, add this class:

```
 <a class='go' href=""><span class="viewMorePs">GO</span></a>
```

This way, your divs will have good height

You can see changes here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jn4144b9/13/

Answer (score -1):

add `overflow: hidden` to `.portalItem`

Answer (score -1):

Add the following style to your `span.viewmoreprefs`

```
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
bottom: 8px;
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cafebabe1991/y2j950t9/1/)

Comment: I added a z-index to make your button appear above your div.

Answer (score -1):

```
.portalItem{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border:1px solid blue;
    padding-bottom:15px; //give some padding here
}
```

[Demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/jn4144b9/14/)